# What does buy-one-give-one mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across this sentence in [Raspberry Pi's FAQs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#buyingBOGO):

> Is there a buy-one-give-one program?

I try to google "buy-one-give-one", but I cannot find the meaning of it. Instead, I found the following usages of "buy-one-give-one":

> buy-one-give-one model
>
> buy-one-give-one companies
>
> buy-one-give-one glasses
>
> buy-one-give-one shoes
>
> buy-one-give-one gifts

What does buy-one-give-one mean?

Comment: If you google "buy-one-give-one", among the first page of results are things like [this Shopwithmeaning page](http://shopwithmeaning.org/buy-one-give-one-companies/) that says "These buy one give one companies like the TOMS Shoes One for One Movement donate one product to those in need for every one product you buy.  The one for one companies that we’ve highlighted support worth social causes with each purchase.  When ever you buy one item, they donate a similar item to those in need."

Comment: By the way, I notice that Shopwithmeaning has a typo in that excerpt; it should be "**worthy** social causes", not "worth social causes."  Also probably "whenever", not "when ever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that when you buy one of the product, another one is donated, usually to a charity.  If you bought a Raspberry Pi with a buy-one-give-one program, you would pay some money, and the company would send one Raspberry Pi to you and another to a charity.

As far as I know, the concept originated with the [OLPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLPC_XO), although they called it "Give One Get One".